# Tag scores on main site are different from iOS app

Tags: bug, tags, reputation, ios-app

Just noticed that my score in various tags differs between the desktop SO site and my iOS app. For example, on the app my MySQL score is 100:

[image]

Yet on the website it is 91:

[image]

Is there a reason these are different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug, I think this is [a deliberate design decision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212299/tag-score-calculation-wrong-in-android-app), because while on the Stack Overflow website you can hover over a tag to get your tag question score, you can't do that with the iOS app, so the dev team combined your question and answer score together in a tag into one for the iOS app, just like they did for the Android app.

The dev team wasn't sure if this was the best way to represent your tag score though, so if you have any better suggestions, try put them forward in a feature request:

> Honestly, we weren't sure how to handle this in the app were there's
>   no such thing as a tooltip. We discussed it but couldn't come to a
>   real conclusion, so we just picked one solution for now; we're open to
>   changing how it's displayed if a good case can be made for any
>   version.

The funny thing about this is, for the mobile version of SO, you can't get tooltip hovers either, so it's just not possible to see your total question score in a tag, just your answer score.

Comment: Nice one. I see the problem, but is presenting different totals as the primary result an ideal solution? Not sure... Thanks cupcake