# Tag scores reflects differently in Stack Overflow web app and Android app

Tags: support, bug, android-app, mobile-web

I mostly use the Stack Overflow web application, but sometimes use the Stack Exchange Android app as well. Strangely, the tag scores in my profile page are not in sync. In the web app it shows correctly, but in the Android app it shows an incorrect number.

For example: My [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) Tag score in the web app shows `656`, which is correct, but in the Android app it shows `673` (sometimes `683` or more).

I thought, probably the Android app is smart and doing some predictive analysis and showing me the future score on that tag... LOL :)

It looks like a bug/defect to me. Can someone from SE verify the same?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com ?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266346/tag-scores-on-main-site-are-different-from-ios-app - not sure if it's the same for android

Comment: Incident already reported but the confusing idea not improved yet... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212299/tag-score-calculation-wrong-in-android-app

Answer (score 2):

- `673` is the sum of your answer and question scores.
- `656` is just your answer score.

You shouldn't blame caching. ;)